# VPN between two offices and one AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I have a VPN connection between our firewall in the NY office and AWS. On the AWS side i have:
1 - customer gateway.
1 - virtual private gateway.
1 - VPN connection.
1 - VPC associated with the virtual private gateway.

I want to create a second VPN tunnel between the Miami office and the same VPC where I currently have my AWS hosted Servers. So that the New York and Miami offices can reach the same servers on that one VPC.

I've created a second customer gateway with the public IP of the Miami office. But I cant attach the VPC to the new virtual private gateway that I have also created.

Can anyone help with some guidelines?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach only one Virtual Private Gateway to VPC ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-gateways)). You can however use the same VPG with multiple VPN connections ([ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/adminguide/Introduction.html#MultipleVPNConnections)).